# Specific search with Cloudant and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, cloudant

I have a search index on my Cloudant that I query using AngularJS and PHP.

So far I'm not getting specific enough results.

For instance, on a search with `fair:'Fair 2017'`, I'm getting all the results that include `Fair`, including `Fair 2016` and so on.

I've tried different search types (simple, standard, classic), and it happens with all of them.

A typical object:

```
doc:Object
  exhibitortype:"Project Space"
  fair:"Fair 2017"
  ...
```

Here's my AngularJS code:

```
$scope.loadexhibitors = function(fair){
  $scope.searchindex = fair.doc.fairname;

  var $promisefairexh=$http({
    url: 'databaseconnect/getexhibitors.php', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {search: $scope.searchindex}
  });
...
```

The PHP bit looks like this:

```
<?php

    $search = $_GET["search"];
    $newsearch = str_replace(' ', '+', $search);

    $url = "https://user:pass.@user.cloudant.com/db/_design/fairs/_search/by_fair?q='$newsearch'&include_docs=true";
    $ch = curl_init();   // initialize curl handle
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And my Cloudant search function:

```
function (doc) {
  index("default", doc.fair);
}
```

On the other hand, on the Cloudant User Interface, when I test the search index and include double quotes on the search input (for example: "Fair 2016" instead of Fair 2016), I get the desired results.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double quotes in your search instead of single quotes, for example:

```
$url = "https://user:pass.@user.cloudant.com/db/_design/fairs/_search/by_fair?q=\"$newsearch\"&include_docs=true";
```

Note the change to the q param:

```
q=\"$newsearch\"
```